# Java: using the constructor with parent class as type parameter

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, constructor

I have a class Timeline with a TreeMap field and a constructor as:

```
public class Timeline{
    private TreeMap<DateTime, Schedulable> schedule;

    public Timeline(TreeMap<DateTime, Schedulable> schedule) {
            this.schedule = schedule;
    }
}
```

And I have a class Activity that has a Timeline as a field:

```
public class Activity extends Schedulable implements Serializable {
    private Timeline legalTimes;

    public Activity() {
        legalTimes = new Timeline(new TreeMap<DateTime, LegalTime>());
        //error here for can't find constructor     ^^^^^
}
```

where LegalTime extends Schedulable.

Requirements:

- Timeline should allow others to schedule any subclass of Schedulable on its timeline (doesn't need to be consistent within the TreeMap)
- Activity's field legalTimes should only have LegalTime on its timeline

I thought this code should work because LegalTime is a subclass of Schedulable. I also can't add a second constructor that takes TreeMap because it has the same erasure.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: offtopic: as a best practice, consider making a defensive copy of TreeMap<DateTime, Schedulable> schedule in the Timeline constructor and assigning the copy to the schedule instance variable.

Answer (score 7):

In general, even if `B` extends `A`, a `Type<B>` is *not* a `Type<A>`, because Java generics are invariant.  This means that a `TreeMap<DateTime, LegalTime>` is not a `TreeMap<DateTime, Schedulable>`, even if `LegalTime` is a `Schedulable`.

Solutions:

- Have the constructor (and corresponding instance variable) be declared to be a `TreeMap<DateTime, ? extends Schedulable>`.

OR

- Make `Timeline` generic, with the generic type parameter being the particular `Schedulable` desired:

Try:

```
public class Timeline<T extends Schedulable> {
    private TreeMap<DateTime, T> schedule;

    public Timeline(TreeMap<DateTime, T> schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }
}
```

And

```
private Timeline<LegalTime> legalTimes;
```

with

```
legalTimes = new Timeline<LegalTime>(new TreeMap<DateTime, LegalTime>());
```

Comment: Doesn't this require that every thing in the TreeMap be of the same subclass of Schedulable? My idea is that some other class could use this as a generic timeline such that it can schedule an Activity or a Meeting or a Commute on the same timeline as long as they extend Schedulable